# Absolute value being an odd function

Tags: functions, absolute-value

Correct me if I am wrong, but I learned that for a function to be symmetrical to the origin, it can be rotated 180 degrees and still appear the same. How is ${x^2 - y^2 = 0}$ an odd function if when it is roatated 180 degrees it appears upside-down?

Comment: That is not a function.

Comment: Symmetry about the origin does not just apply to curves described by functions, but can be applied to other "curves".  What does the graph of $ \ x^2 \ = \ y^2 \ $ look like?

Comment: A graph has symmetry with respect to the origin if $(-x,-y)$ is on the graph whenever $(x,y)$ is. A graph has symmetry with respect to the $y$-axis if $(-x,y)$ is on the graph whenever $(x,y)$ is. The squares in $x^2-y^2=0$ guarantee both of these symmetries.

Comment: And your title makes no sense: $x^2-y^2=0$ doesn't give you the "absolute value function." It gives you $y=\pm|x|$, a pair of lines of slope $\pm1$ intersecting at the origin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a function because there are two outputs for one input, so since this is not a function it doesn't obey these rules. Trust the King.